# How to ask, programmatically, a compiler to compile a file in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc

The following is my C++ program:

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ofstream fileWriter;
    fileWriter.open ("firstFile.cpp");
    fileWriter << "#include <iostream>" << endl;
    fileWriter << "int main() {" << endl;
    fileWriter << "\tstd::cout << \"hello world\" << std::endl;" << endl;
    fileWriter << "\treturn 0;" << endl;
    fileWriter << "}" << endl;
    fileWriter.close();

    return 0;
}
```

When the above program is executed, it creates a text-file named "firstFile.cpp" containing the following code:

*firstFile.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which, when executed, prints "hello world" on the screen.

So, I would like to add to the *main.cpp* file lines of code asking GCC to compile the new *firstFile.cpp* just created.

I am using GNU gcc on both platform Ubuntu and Windows.

Is it possible to get any error code form the call to the compiler? If not why.

Comment: The [`system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function might be helpful.

Comment: You want to run the "GCC" to process that file. You surely can do that by hand in the console. So, you can do that in your program too. You can simply try `system("g++ -c foobar.cpp")` and it will do the same thing as if written in console, but that will just **start a separate process that runs the G++** with that arguments. This alone is probably not what you really want. You probably also want to read the results/warnings/errors later. I'd suggest you edit your question, remove the "how I generated the text file" part, and focus on asking about what you want to do to it afterwards.

Comment: First of all use g++ instead gcc. gcc is for compiling C source code. g++ is for C++ source code.

Comment: @secretgenes man gcc: `gcc - GNU project C and C++ compiler`

Comment: @Ninda maybe you should ask a new question about getting the return value.

Comment: @OrangeDog: technically correct, but practically irrelevant. gcc misses many default options (about linker, include paths and whatnot) required to compile correctly C++ programs. If you try to compile any non-trivial C++ program with gcc you typically end up with linker errors or (on more "complicated" targets) subtle malfunctions.

Comment: @OrangeDog : Though you can compile C++ source code with gcc compiler but it has object linking issues. g++ while linking objects automatically links in the std C++ libraries while this is not the case with gcc.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that C++ is some kind of fancy-dancy language with reflection and REPLs and other nancy-boy features.  C++ is for real men, and real men don't use code generators.  They use emacs macros.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is not too difficult using the [std::system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) command. Also [raw string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) allow us to insert *multiline text* which is useful for typing in program parts:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

// Use raw string literal for easy coding
auto prog = R"~(

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << '\n';
}

)~"; // raw string literal stops here

int main()
{
    // save program to disk
    std::ofstream("prog.cpp") << prog;

    std::system("g++ -o prog prog.cpp"); // compile
    std::system("./prog"); // run
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: Watch out for various attacks though - this code runs the default shell process. Don't pass any untrusted user input to `system` and be mindful of who can control the environment such as PATH, .bashrc, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the extra information regarding raw string literals.

Comment: Thanks, I have programmed C++ for quite a while but I _never_ knew about raw string literals. I thought it was just one of those handy features that C# and even PHP has but C++ lacked... glad to be proven wrong!

Comment: @CompuChip - To be fair, they are a relatively new feature (as of C++11).   Older compilers might not support them, so if you're sharing code with people using legacy systems, you might want to avoid them.  Otherwise, yes, they are quite handy.

Comment: OP mentions Ubuntu and Windows. I don't think `std::system("./prog");` will work as expected on windows.

Comment: @CoolGuy I don't have `Windows` to check with but I was under the impression that Windows` accepts forward slash these days. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Galik, you are correct. In fact, I'd argue that you *should* use the forward slash for everything except UI elements. The reason is simply compatibility with other OSes. I'd consider it also ideal to avoid having to switch between conventions when working with HTTP (etc) URLs. Forward slashes also don't require escaping while backslashes typically will (and thus a possible bug in waiting).

Comment: @OrangeDog I can understand the warning for using `system` with unchecked input but shouldn't you also include a warning for the C++ code being compiled? That could do even more things, including calling `system`

Comment: @JimmyT. the code being compiled is part of what is passed, so already covered by the warning.

Answer (score 15):

`gcc` is an executable, so you have to use either `system("gcc myfile.cpp")` or `popen("gcc myfile.cpp")`, which gives you a filestream as result.

But since you are generating code anyways, you don't even need to write it to a file. You can open the gcc proces with `FILE* f = popen("gcc -x c++  <whatever flags> -")`. Then you have you can write your code with `fwrite(f, "<c++ code>")`. I know this is `c` and not really `c++` but it might be useful. ( I don't think there is a `c++` version of `popen()`).

Comment: Indeed popen(...) allow to get the console's result of the callee command(anything the called command should print to the screen). As explain here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807755/reading-popen-results-in-c

Answer (score 13):

All you need to do is add the following line after you create your file.

```
system("g++ firstFile.cpp -o hello");
```

Works on OS X so I hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 7):

**To use the command line of a compiler in source file use system function.**

**Syntax** of which is :

```
int system (const char* command); //built in function of g++ compiler.
```

In your case, it should be like

```
system("g++ firstFile.cpp");
```

**PS: system function does not throw Exceptions.**

**Program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ofstream fileWriter;
    fileWriter.open ("firstFile.cpp");
    fileWriter << "#include <iostream>" << endl;
    fileWriter << "int main() {" << endl;
    fileWriter << "\tstd::cout << \"hello world\" << std::endl;" << endl;
    fileWriter << "\treturn 0;" << endl;
    fileWriter << "}" << endl;
    fileWriter.close();

    system("g++ firstFile.cpp");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there not another way for C++ to get exeptions @secretgenes

Comment: @Ninda : you can catch exceptions when it arises in the try block, but in the case of system function, no exceptions are generated so it doesn't throw any exceptions to be caught in catch block.

Comment: Doesn't `system` require `cstdlib`?

Comment: @CoolGuy: ya my bad, it dose require cstdlib. but it works fine in vs2012 without even including cstdlib.

Comment: @secretgenes is there a way to do the same on windows10?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what you actually want to achieve you could also consider [embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23058873/1116364) some C++ compiler into your application.

Note that this is by far not as easy as calling an external executable, and might be subject to licence restrictions (GPL).

Also note that by using `std::system` or a similar mechanism you add the requirement on your target environment to actually have the called compiler available (unless you somehow bundle it with your application).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ofstream fileWriter;
    fileWriter.open ("firstFile.cpp");
    fileWriter << "#include <iostream>" << endl;
    fileWriter << "int main() {" << endl;
    fileWriter << "\tstd::cout << \"hello world\" << std::endl;" << endl;
    fileWriter << "\treturn 0;" << endl;
    fileWriter << "}" << endl;
    fileWriter.close();

    system("c firstFile.cpp");

    return 0;
}
```

or whatever command is appropriate for the compiler you're using.

Comment: Doesn't `system` require `cstdlib`?

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes, you need to #include <cstdlib> in order to use system